# In Java, what is the difference between this.method() and method()?

Tags: java, methods

Is there any difference between calling `this.method()` and `method()` (including performance difference)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The only time it matters is if you are using `OuterClass.this.method()` e.g.

```
class OuterClass {
    void method() { }

    class InnerClass {
        void method() {
            OuterClass.this.method(); // not the same as method().
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: though, it's the same as OuterClass.method() in case method is static

Comment: Strictly speaking, IMHO you cannot compare OuterClass.this.method() with method() since we are just comparing leaving or putting "this." in/out.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this special example, Peter.

Comment: Why InnerClass is declared with with round brackets ()?

Comment: @Peter17, My built in compiler was broken. ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 30):

There is absolutely no difference between these constructs and the generated bytecode will be exactly the same, hence no performance impact. `this` is resolved during compilation if not explicitly defined.

The only reason for using explicit `this` is readability - some people find it easier to read because `this` suggests that this is an instance method of current object.

Also please note that if `method()` is static, using `this` is discouraged and misleading.

```
private static void method() {
}

private void foo() {
    this.method();    //generates warning in my IDE for a reason
}
```

And in this case it will also have no effect on performance.

Comment: If the method is static it's not correct.  My compiler will tell me that there is no "this" pointer for a static method.

Comment: @duffymo: I clarified what I meant about `static` methods.

Comment: Thank you, Tomasz.  No down votes from me; your clarification is perfect.

Comment: There is some readability involved, yes, but that should also be caught by syntax highlighting. For me, it's become a bit of a (bad?) habit because typing this. is faster / more comfortable than ctrl+space.

Answer (score 19):

That there is no difference can be seen by calling `javap -c ClassName` on the commandline.
For example:

```
public class This {
    private void method() {
    }
    public void noThis() {
        method();
    }
    public void useThis() {
        this.method();
    }
}
```

Produces the following disassembled output:

```
Compiled from "This.java"
public class This extends java.lang.Object{
public This();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public void noThis();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #2; //Method method:()V
   4:   return

public void useThis();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #2; //Method method:()V
   4:   return

}
```

Comment: The only difference is probably those few microseconds at compile time when it figures out the implicit `this`.

Answer (score 5):

For methods there is no difference, but it can make a difference with fields.  Consider this code:

```
private String someObject = "some value";

public String someMethod(String someObject) {
     //this.someObject refers to the field while
     //someObject refers to the parameter
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference - At least there is no performance impact. I prefer not writing "this" - The IDE can usually highlight calls to this anyway, and I think it is less readable when every access to methods/fields/... start with "this.". But it really is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference at all other than the readability. It makes it more clearer to the reader.

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder: I find it more noisy because the information of `this` is redundant, since it is implicit. It might help newbies, it is annoying for (most) more experienced coders.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.method()` and/or `this.myVar` or don't - on methods there is no difference, on vars there may be - but be consistent about it. I see it sprinkled throughout code, sometimes I even see `this.m_myClassVar`.

Personally I prefer to prefix my class vars with a simple underscore and put a trailing underscore on my method args:

```
public MyClass
{
    private int _myInt;

    public void myMethod(final int myInt_, final int fooFactor_)
    {
        _myInt = myInt_ * fooFactor_;
    }
}
```

Although most IDEs will make it clear which is which, I find this tends to prevent misassignment and makes the intentions of the code clearer and IMO easier to read.

I do use `_thisInstance.myMethod()` (where `_thisInstance` is a reference to the outer class) or `_thisInstance._myVar`, in inner classes/listeners/threads/etc. where I need to be clear about what method on which class I am calling and/or where I need to have a reference to a class instance.

Comment: Use of underscores in variable names goes against the Java naming conventions for non-constant variables.

Answer (score 1):

Using this.method() makes clear that a function associated with the instance of the class is being invoked, as opposed to a static function or one belonging to another object.

It's in the spirit of those C++ developers who like to prepend "m_" on all member variables in a class.  It makes ownership unambiguous.  I tend to like it, but it's not as important when you're using an IDE that clarifies such things using colors and fonts.

Comment: "*one belonging to another object*" Well, it is necessarily prefixed by the other object, no? "*as opposed to a static function*" Is the distinction important?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried to do this.variable in the constructor?

In theory, in C++, since the object has not yet been created there is no this. I am not sure of the case in Java.

Comment: Works in Java because `this.foo = foo;` is a very common pattern to init fields (member variables) from parameters of same name.