# java this keyword

Tags: java, this

I have read that in Java you don't have to explicitly bind the **this** keyword  to object, it is done by interpreter.  It is opposite to Javascript where you always have to know the value of **this**. But where is **this** in Java is pointing - to class or object ? Or does it vary ?
This question is a part of my attempt to understand basic OO concepts and design patterns so I can apply them to Javascript. 
Thank you.

Comment: This tutorial should help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: This is quite easily answered using almighty google

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java this.method() vs method()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547310/java-this-method-vs-method)

Comment: What do you mean by 'explicitly bind to object'? And how is that different in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) states:

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value
>   that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was
>   invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

I.e. it always points to an object, not a class.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, `this` always refers to an object and never to a class.

Answer (score 1):

in java `this is refer Current object`

like

```
public class Employee{

String name,adress;

Employee(){

 this.name="employee";
 this.address="address";

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to current object.

*Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.*

Answer (score 1):

In java 'this' is a keyword, basically used to refer to the current object. In the following example the setter methods are using 'this' to set the values of name and age of current object.

```
public class Person {

  String name;
  int age;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("Rishi");
    p.setAge(23);
    System.out.println(p.getName() + " is " + p.getAge() + " years old");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation (found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

What this means is that inside the code of any class, when you write `this`, you specify the fact that you are referring to the current object.

As a side note, you cannot use `this` with static fields or methods because they do not belong to any specific object (**instance** of the class).

Comment: That's not the 'official documentation', it's a tutorial. The official documentation is the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

this keyword is always used in referencing the object of the current class.
where as this() is used for the current class constructors.
for example:

```
    class circle {
        
        public int radius;
        public Circle() {
           this.radius = 10; //any default value
        }

        public Circle(int radius) {
           this.radius = radius  // here this.radius will set instance variable radius
        }
        public int areaOfCircle() {
              return 3.14*radius*radius;
        }
    }
```