# Using this. in Java

Tags: java, this

I know that both chunks of code work but as I am trying to understand the use of "this" I would really appreciate it if you could explain me why the class Vehicle1 is 'better' than Vehicle2.
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
public class Vehicle1 {
  private String color;

  Vehicle(String c) {
    this.setVehicle(c);
  }
  Vehicle() {
    this.setVehicle("Red");;
  }
  public void setVehicle(String c) {
      this.color = c;
  }
  public String getVehicle() {
      return color;
  }
}


public class Vehicle2 {
  private String color;

  Vehicle(String c) {
    color = c;
  }
  Vehicle() {
    color = "Red";
  }
  public String getVehicle() {
      return color;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666276/java-this-keyword

Comment: The second version is actually better. But that has nothing to do with the use of `this`. A constructor shouldn't call an overridable method. Why do you name setVehicle()/getVehicle() methods that set and get the color. Why not setColor()/getColor()?

Comment: `this` is a reference the current Object. You can use `this` to do everything you could do with a final variable (you can't assign it), plus (as the first statement in a constructor) invoking another constructor.

Comment: `this.` as a method prefix is utterly useless. Your constructors do not chain. You have doubled semicolons. The first example calls an overridable method from a constructor. The constructors are not public. Both examples are crap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's largely a matter of preference, but one advantage to using `this` is that it avoids naming collisions with more local variables. For example, if you wanted people calling your constructor to know that its argument is supposed to be a *color*, you might want to name it such:

```
  Vehicle(String color) {
    color = color;        // This doesn't set the field.
  }
```

The code above shows, without using `this`, that the field name `color` is now usurped by the local parameter name. Depending on your settings, you may get some compiler warnings, but it's possible to overlook that bug.

If you use `this.`, then everything continues working with no additional changes:

```
  Vehicle(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vehicle 1 is better because it removes any ambiguity or confusion. In vehicle 2, if you have another "color" variable inside a method, then you will be dealing with that local variable, rather than the color of the car itself.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There was no ambiguity in the first example, so it couldn't be reduced. You cannot have less than zero ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

We use `this` if local variable, or method argument may shadow class property.
It points that this particular reference will be found within class properties.

Example:

The main difference can be seen when method/local  properties are the same as instance properties:

This code does exactly as we expect, assign value to `color` property:

```
public void setVehicle(String c) {
   this.color = c;
}
```

So here `this` is not necssary, because method argument name does not shadow property `color`.

But if we would use same argument name as property name:

```
public void setVehicle(String color) {
   color = color;
}
```

then it would mean assign method argument `color` to itself, which has no point.

So if we want to set a new property value, we need to use `this`, in order to tell the compiler that `color` is a instance property, not local a variable.