# What does "this" mean?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java this.method() vs method()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547310/java-this-method-vs-method)

I've been reading some things and doing some tutorials about android java but I still dont understand what "this" means, like in the following code.

```
    View continueButton = this.findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View newButton = this.findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Also why is it in this example that a button is not defined with Button but with View, what is the difference?

ps. Great site!! trying to learn java and got ALLOT of answers by searching here!

Comment: You can't know. Because `this` is the receiver of the method in which this code is present. As we don't have the code, we can't answer.

Comment: Here's the official Java explanation of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: @Mark Not necessarily a dupe of that question, since the OP also asks about `setOnClickListener(this)`

Comment: read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming) and then find a good Object Oriented programming tutorial ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` keyword is [a reference to the current object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html). It is used to pass *this* instance of the object, and more.

For example, these two allocations are equal:

```
class Test{

    int a;

    public Test(){
        a = 5;
        this.a = 5;
    }

}
```

Sometimes you have a hidden field you want to access:

```
class Test{

    int a;

    public Test(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Here you assigned the field `a` with the value in the parameter `a`.

The `this` keyword works the same way with methods. Again, these two are the same:

```
this.findViewById(R.id.myid);
findViewById(R.id.myid);
```

Finally, say you have a class MyObject that has a method which takes a MyObject parameter:

```
class MyObject{

    public static void myMethod(MyObject object){
        //Do something
    }

    public MyObject(){
        myMethod(this);
    }

}
```

In this last example you passed a reference of the current object to a static method.

> Also why is it in this example that a button is not defined with Button but with View, what is the difference?

In Android SDK, a `Button` is a [subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) of `View`. You can request the `Button` as a `View` and [cast](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) the `View` to a `Button`:

```
Button newButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.new_button);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is referring to the instance of the object that is being acted upon.

In the case that you have above, `this.findViewById(R.id.continue_button)` this is referring to a method in a parent class (Specifically either [`Activity.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) or [`View.findViewByid()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29), assuming you are writing your own subclass of `Activity` or `View`!).

Comment: That code could be placed within a custom View and it would still work perfectly. Saying its only Activity.findViewById() is not perfectly correct.

Comment: "this.someMethod" doesn't necessarily call the method in the parent class. In fact, `this` doesn't add information in this case, the way say, `super` would. (Unless by "parent class" you meant "the class of this instance).

Comment: @HandlerExploit Thank you for pointing that out.  I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is the current object instance.

```
class Blaa
{
   int bar=0;
   public Blaa()
   {}
   public void mogrify(int bar,Blaa that)
   {
       bar=1; //changes the local variable bar
       this.bar=1; //changes the member variable bar. 
       that.bar=1; //changes "that"'s member variable bar. 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current instance of a class

Comment: `this` is NOT the current instance . its a pointer to the current instance.

Comment: @JayD notice the word 'refers' in my answer above, there are _no_ pointers in Java only references.

Comment: check this link for this keyword.. http://www.javabeat.net/qna/16-what-is-super-and-this-keyword-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

`this` in Java is a reference to the current object instance. So if you are writing a method for class `MyClass`, `this` is the current instance of `MyClass`.

Note that in your case, writing `this.findViewById(...)` isn't really necessary, and may be considered bad style.

Answer (score 0):

"this" in object oriented languages such as java, c# is a reference to the object on which you are invoking the method or whose data you are accessing.

See if this link is helpful for you in understanding the "this" more -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html