# the role of "this" in TextView textView = new TextView(this);

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming. I want to know that in this code what does the `this` in

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

this would point to which class or method? I copied this code from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html/ this refers to Context and check the constructors of TextView @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: [Using the this Keyword in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you need `this` when creating a `TextView` is because one of the the constructors of `TextView` (the one that you're calling) takes a `Context` object as a parameter.

That basically means you must give `TextView` a `Context` in order to create it.

Where do you get this context from? Well, an activity is a kind of context (`Activity` is a subclass of `Context`)! And you're creating the `TextView` in an activity class right? So just use this activity as the context!

Got it? Use *this* activity as the context for the `TextView`! That's why you put `this` in there. `this` refers to the object that the code is currently running on.

Since `this` refers to an object created from the class, you can't use `this` in a static method because a the code in a static method does not run on any object.

Another use of `this` is in constructors:

```
class MyClass {
    private int a, b;

    public MyClass(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Since the compiler can't know which `a` or `b` you mean, you must add `this` to refer the `a` that's in the class.

Answer (score -1):

`this` refers to the current object's instance that was invoked or initialized.

See: [What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921167/what-does-this-mean)