# Difference between this.mCtx and mCtx Android

Tags: java

If I create a class that looks like this:

```
public class TagManager {
private final Context mCtx;

public TagManager (Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}
```

}

What is the difference between using

> this.mCtx = ctx;

versus

> mCtx = ctx;

As far as I can tell they both do the same thing but I can't find any discussion of it.

Comment: Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html out.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6547327/1166813 answer, since it is the same for variables and methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure it's the same. It's just a matter of CodeStyle - it's up to you to select what you like more.

The only reasonable case to make this.*** is when your argument and member variable have the same name. For example

```
    private final Context ctx;
    public TagManager (Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
```

However, Android Code Style tells us to use m*** prefix for member variables, so this situation should rare happen in your classes.

Good luck

Comment: Good answer, thanks.  Gave it to you because you threw in the m*** prefix info :)

Answer (score 2):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, **this** is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

`this.x` on the example refer to `public int x` no `int x`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
public class foo {
private final int bla = 1;

public int blabla () {
    int bla = 2;
    return bla;//this will return 2
}
```

/

```
public class foo {
private final int bla = 1;

public int blabla () {
    int bla = 2;
    return this.bla;//this will return 1
}
```