# Why is the super method not visible/resolved?

Tags: java, visibility, javac, overloading

```
interface Problematic {
    void method();
}
class Parent {
    void method(int arg) { }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void test() {
        new Problematic() {
            @Override public void method() { 
                // javac error: method method in class <anonymous Problematic> cannot be applied to given types;
                // required: no arguments, found: int
                method(0);
                Child.this.method(0); // works just fine
                Child.super.method(0); // works just fine
            }
        };
    }
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA also gives a warning:

> Method 'method()' recurses infinitely, and can only end by throwing an exception

Comment: This question is a duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547310/java-this-method-vs-method

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I know how it works, I'm still asking "Why?" and Sotirios' answer is the level I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Java Language Specification,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)

> If the form is `MethodName`, that is, just an Identifier, then:
>
> If the Identifier appears in the scope of a visible method declaration
>   with that name (§6.3, §6.4.1), then:
>
> - **If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, let `T` be the innermost such type declaration. The class or
>     interface to search is `T`.**
> - This search policy is called the "comb rule". It effectively looks for methods in a nested class's superclass hierarchy before looking
>     for methods in an enclosing class and its superclass hierarchy. See
>     §6.5.7.1 for an example.
> - Otherwise, the visible method declaration may be in scope due to one or more single-static-import or static-import-on-demand declarations.
>     There is no class or interface to search, as the method to be invoked
>     is determined later (§15.12.2.1).

You're invoking the method inside the anonymous inner class which is a subtype of `Problematic`. This makes `Child` its enclosing type. In your case, `T` is the anonymous inner class, since that is the innermost type. Because of this, the class to search for the method is `T`, ie. the anonymous subclass of `Problematic`.

In [later](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) steps of [the resolution of method invocation expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), it is decided that the method `Problematic#method()` takes no arguments since it declares no parameters. It is therefore not applicable and a compiler error is raised.

Comment: Your last sentence is confusing, can you please clarify?: the `method(int)` in `Child` has the exact parameter list of the calling expression.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Hmm, let me review. Please remove your accept.

Comment: It looks like it happily finds `Child$1.method` using the name and then it doesn't find a correct argument list: `required: no arguments, found: int`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Was too eager and shot myself in the foot there, sorry. Fixed. The innermost type is the anonymous subtype of `Problematic`. I had mistakenly read that `T` is the directly enclosing type.

Comment: I would've thought that the compiler would go back to `15.12.1` after that fail and try the search again while ignoring `Problematic.method` this time which would lead to "correctly"? finding `Parent.method`. They must have had their reasons not doing that.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Considering that you can nest inner classes pretty far, such a process might be too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html:

> Shadowing
>
> If a declaration of a type (such as a member variable or a parameter name) in a particular scope (such as an inner class or a method definition) has the same name as another declaration in the enclosing scope, then the declaration shadows the declaration of the enclosing scope.

Comment: I just found the same: [Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

An overload in a child class hides the method being overloaded in the parent class. In this case, `Problematic.method()` overloads and hides `Parent.method(int).`

Comment: I think he means `Child$1.method()`

Comment: `Child$1.method()` clearing isn't overloading `Parent.method(int)`, because `Child$1` doesn't inherit from `Parent`.

Comment: You were onto something, the correct term here is [shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27337473/253468).

Answer (score 0):

### Explicit is always better than implicit!

`method(0)` is actually `this.method(0)` which is actually `Child$1.this.method(0)` and `Child$1.this.method(int)` does not exist in the declaration of `Problematic`.

This is explained in the error messages from the compiler and from the IDE.

The compiler tells you that this is exactly what it is doing, it is resolving to the most local scope and finding something and that something isn't correct and it stops looking.

#### You are doing this:

```
@Override public void method() { 
    // javac error: method method in class <anonymous Problematic> cannot be applied to given types;
    // required: no arguments, found: int
    method(0);
    Child.this.method(0); // works just fine
    Child.super.method(0); // works just fine
}
```

#### Which actually implicitly means the following:

```
@Override public void method() { 
    // javac error: method method in class <anonymous Problematic> cannot be applied to given types;
    // required: no arguments, found: int
    this.method(0); // this is implied in the above code
                    // and resolves to the Problematic declaration
    Child.this.method(0); // will never be reached if the previous call is actually corrected.
    Child.super.method(0); // will never be reached either
}
```

`this.method(0)` is invalid code and if you called `this.method()` it would just recurse infinitely and throw a `StackOverflow` error.

This is explained in the error messages from the compiler and from the IDE.

This is how the scope resolution works, there is no mystery *why*, read the scope resolution rules and you will see it looks for `this.XXX` first then broadens the scope.

If your goal is to call `method(int)` on `Child` you already know how to do that, you have to call it with `Child.this.method(int)`, it has to be fully qualified because of the namespace scoping resolution.

Comment: Why is it _actually this_? Why is it that when you rename the `Problematic#method` to something else (which isn't the same as the name of the `Parent` method, this problem goes away?

Comment: Inner classes can call methods in the container class without qualifying them. Usually. The weirdness here is that `method(0)` isn't read as a call to the exactly matching method in the container class.

Comment: If you correct `method(0)` to `method()` you're calling a different method: `Parent.method(int)` versus `Child$1.method()` defined as `Problematic.method()`.

Comment: There is no `method()` on anything but your anonymous inner class, if you correct it, it will just recurse and crash. You admit that correcting it makes it correct. How it is no is invalid code.

Comment: It won't be correct because I want to call the method implemented in `Parent`, not call itself and cause infinite recursion.

Comment: I suspect that inner class can call method of outer class without qualifier only if there is no name collision. In other cases the `meth()` is `this.meth()`.

Comment: That bit about how scoping resolution works might actually be an answer to the question, but all the stuff about the OP not understanding interfaces seems like a complete misreading of the question.