# This and super keyword usage in android

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I am new to android and java and i can not get my head around understanding why in android "this" keyword is sometimes used and not "super"?

Also how can you call parent methods without "this" or "super" keyword.

For example lets say we have

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

We can see that in above example MainActivety class does not have setContentView method in fact this method is defined in ActionBarActivity as

```
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    this.getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}
```

So how are we able to call it without "this" or "super"?

Why does it still work if we would put "this" infront although the method is defined in parent class isnt "this" keyword meant for current scope/class.

Comment: An expression of a subtype always has access to accessible supertype methods.

Comment: You should first take a look at the Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: You also should read up on inheritance my friend https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Basic OOP tutorial should answer all of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the difference between this.method() and method()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547310/in-java-what-is-the-difference-between-this-method-and-method)

Comment: There is no difference between 'this.method()' and 'method()'.

Comment: @Lew that's not always true

Comment: When is it different, @TimCastelijns?

Comment: @Lew when called from an inner class

Comment: You're right. If `method` is part of the containing class, then the inner class can call `method()` but not `this.method()`. Good call. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you call parent methods without "this" or "super" keyword?

You can without `super` provided that the method you call is not redefined in the "current" class, if it is redefined you may need to disambiguate the call:

```
class A {
  public void f() {}
  public void h() {} 
  public void i() {} 
}

class B extends A {
  public void g() { f(); } // same as super.f()
  public void h() { h(); /* recursive call */ }
  public void i() { super.i(); /* call to inherited but "masked" */ }
}
```

> how are we able to call it without "this" or "super"?

`this` is not mandatory, when you write `something` in an instance method, it is read as `this.something`. This is why in the preceding example, the call `h()` is a recursive one.

`this` is not scoped, it denotes the "full" object itself. `super` scopes what follows. `this` is typed with the current class, and `super` is the object typed as its parent class.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you don't have to explicitly add `this` every single time you want to access a field or invoke a method in your derived class **or** the parent class. Extending a class basically means inheriting all the properties of the parent class, while creating a completely new type. The `this` keyword refers to the instance that's created when instantiating through `MyClass instance = new MyClass()`, not the `MyClass` definition. If you want to set a variable on the class scope, you can use a [static field](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html#static-and-non-static-fields).

However, when you have a local variable defined, lets say as an argument to a method (`void method(String startActivity){}`), then that local definition will override access to the definition in `this`, therefor requiring the explicit `this` keyword.

As for the super call, when you override a method in Java you can call the original method that you have overridden by using `super.<the method name>()`. This is needed because in the class there's no longer a notion of the original method.

Answer (score 0):

because this keyword can have the direct access of class attributes and method in that class only while super keyword is used in inherited class for accessing the attributes and method without creating the objects.